# How To Access Python Code Through Web-Server

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, webserver

I have a game which I'm programming in Visual Studio on my pc. However, I want to store a database for the game on a remote 'web server' where I can make queries to it rather than storing it within the game (to save memory). I also have a few machine learning algorithms and I'd like train them seperately and also store these on some sort of web server so I can make requests to make predictions with the models.

Are there any modules that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like a google cloud? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage

Comment: Here's just one of the many ways you could do this: Run a Flask server that performs Python tasks when it receives POST requests

Comment: I meant whoever is playing the game would be able to request to use the algorithm from their side if that makes sense. I'll look at Flask, thanks!

Comment: Also, it'd have to be functional cross-platform as I'm trying to make the game playable on android (Kivy).